# Preventing from converting "Text to columns" for new Excel workbook's

Tags: excel, csv

I want to prevent my Excel to re-use the latest "Text to column"'s specifications when open a new "CSV" file, since my new file's specs are quite different from latest used.

Taken steps:

**First file - columns separated by ";"**

1.- File "xxx.csv" is opened

2.- Range A:A is selected

3.- "Text to column" is executed by using ";" as separator

4.- File "xxx.csv" is saved as xlsx and closed

**Second file  - columns separated by ";"**

1.- The file "zzz.csv" is opened

2.- No option to use "Text to column" is given since the file is opened with the columns already separated (which is what I don't need)

Answer (score 0):

Finally couldn't do it straight forward, so I've added some VBA code in the workbook's event "open" that does the trick for me.